# Stop Facebook from recording chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

For about 2 weeks now, Facebook has started recording chat messages to my messages inbox.  Is there a way to stop this?  I'm constantly getting notifications when I'm chatting that I've got a new message, it's extremely annoying.

Also, is it possible to delete these from the inbox?  The only option I see is to archive them, not delete.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the chat history in your inbox by opening the message/chat history and clicking  "Actions | Delete Messages". Then at the bottom, click "Delete All". Confirm your choice, and viola, your chat history is no more.

Alternatively: https://www.facebook.com/help/new/?faq=12886

And also by that help article, it looks like the option to not save chat history is impossible.

Comment: That won't delete the message in the other it, will it?